# How to change TFS changeset owner by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs, merge, changeset

I need to change merged changesets owner in TFS because it need to be owner who check-in changes, but not who merged down to branches. Please help.

Comment: I would say this is a bad practice. One of source control's purposes is to provide an audit trail of who did what and when. If you start messing with the audit trail then you loose accountability. In addition to this a merge might contain many checkins from many users. If the merge contains 100 changesets how to you decide who the merge should be assigned to (hint, it's the person who did the merge)

Comment: @James Reed. Try to understand me. I wish the same. But by the raeson of only me merging changests to release branch - only me owner of all changesets, I want to restore original owner.

Comment: If you did the merge, you are the owner of that change set. This is how things are supposed to work.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/view-where-when-changesets-have-been-merged

Comment: @James Reed. Now- yes. And what?

Comment: You don't need to modify the checkin info. You can see that you did the merge (which is correct) , if you track the change set history you can see who did the original checkins that have been included in the merge.

Comment: @James Reed. I know i can track. But i need to see original owner in my CI system. And not only me watching changesets at release, another users too, and they no rights to track.

Comment: Then your process is broken. You need to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Change changeset owner is not support in TFS. There are all original data. If you can change the owner of changeset follow one's inclinationsly, how could you determine which is the really owner. Obviously, this violates the principle of the source control.

For your situation, suggest you can add the info in changeset's comment to note who check-in changes.